# Will tensor.backward computes all the gradient in graph?

Tags: pytorch

I read these codes on github:

```
# loss1, loss2 belong to the same net
net.zero_grad()
loss1 = ...
loss2 = ...
loss1.backward()
loss2.backward()
optim.step()
```

which is not a mentioned BP method on pytorch official website, and  official documentation mention `Computes the gradient of current tensor w.r.t. graph leaves.` for `tensor.backward`.

So, other gradients expect the two loss tensors are not computed? And no tensors are updated?

Answer (score 0):

`loss.backwards()` computes the gradients for all variables in the graph w.r.t the loss function. The parameters are being updated according to the accumulated gradients in `optim.step()`. In your code, you back propagate twice (one for each loss), the gradients are being accumulated, and only after accumulating both gradients, parameters are being updated by the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks, and I still get two more questions: Q1. code like: `optim=optim(net1_param + net2_param); out1 = net1(); out2 = net2(out1); out2.backward(); optim.step()`. Will net1_param get updated?  Q2: How should I deal with different loss weights in this method?

Comment: @inkzk Add these sub-questions to your question.